# Show a Toast when user change setting in preferences activity

Tags: android, preferences, toast, listpreference

I have a preferences Activity with a ListPreference on it and I use this preferences in another activity,
But I want to show a Toast whenever, user changing option in preference Activity.
For example, when user clicks on second radio button in ListPreference, suddenly a toast shown and says "second".

Comment: @mango I have just created a pref activity to make it show preferences, but i don't know where i should define a code to show a toast, in pref activity maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem?

Resolve the preference and set a listener that does the toast?
Something like this for example

```
ListPreference listPreference = findPreference(key);
    listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, I want something exactly like this! I understand other lines than first line. what is (key)? how should I fill that?

Comment: @Reza_Rg Sometimes the man pages can be your friend, take a read of this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceGroup.html#findPreference%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and then look at your preferences.xml file, the light bulb moment will come shortly thereafter.