# onPreferenceChange method isn't called when Listpreferences changes

Tags: android, preferences, toast

I have a Preferences Activity in my code.
I want to show a toast when ever user change radio button in a ListPreferences.
I used this code but it does not work. :(

```
public class PrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);   
    }

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences arg0, String key) {

        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) findPreference(key);
        listPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(PrefsActivity.this, "second", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

what is my problem?

Comment: You should edit this new information into your existing question: [Show a Toast when user change setting in preferences activity](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13665409/1267661), rather than create a new question. Please see the [FAQ] about acceptable ways to get more attention to your questions.

Comment: @Reza_rg : you have try`Log.v("ListPreference", "onPreferenceChange");`  to see onPreferenceChange is called or not in logcat?

Comment: @imrankhan I tried it now, and it seems onPreferenceChange no to be called. what should i do now?

Comment: @Sam Thanks for your notice, I'll remember this for next time.

Comment: @Reza_Rg : then first change question Headline to `onPreferenceChange` instead of Toast is not showing because when onPreferenceChange method is called then Toast automatically show you code for toast is Right

Comment: @imrankhan good point. Done.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change your `onCreate` code to:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);  

   SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

You are not adding the `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to `PrefsActivity` Activity.

Comment: now, I have another problem. :( when i click on one of radio buttons in listpreferences, it toast what i want, but it dose not update value in listpreferences.

Comment: @Reza_Rg : you return false from `onPreferenceChange` - lol - did you read what it does ? - at ρяσѕρєя K - why not unregistering ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Unregister what ?