# Handle SeekBar changes in OnPreferenceChange

Tags: android, user-interface, listener, seekbar

I have a SettingsActivity which implements OnPreferenceChangeListener.
Inside such callback, I would like to handle the SeekBar change:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue)
{
    if(preference.getTitle().equals("My Seek Bar"))
    {
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

But trying something like casting a **Preference** to a **SeekBar** is not an option.

What's the proper way of doing it within the *OnPreferenceChange* callback?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [OnSeekBarChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html) to handle events related to `SeekBars`.

When you create your SettingsActivity, just look for the SeekBar and call:

```
 seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
   void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
      ... your code ....
   }
 });
```

Comment: I added this line in the SeekBarPreference XML node             `android:id="@+id/seekbar"` but if I try and access it in SettingsActivity's onCreate with these lines `SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);         seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener((SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener) this);` I get a NullPointerException. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to achieve the same thing. I know the question is somewhat old but I hope it will still help other people. Trying to get a `SeekBarPreference` as a `SeekBar` won't work, a `NullPointerException` is going to get thrown as it has already got mentioned.

Here is a minimal example that seems to work.

Let's assume that you have a preference screen made with this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SeekBarPreference
    android:id="@+id/slider"
    android:defaultValue="35"
    android:max="100"
    android:title="Slide it"
    android:key="sliderValue">
</SeekBarPreference>

</PreferenceScreen
```

You can get the value like that in your `PreferenceActivity`:

```
 public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
         SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                 .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
         prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String s) {
         // here you get the new slider value
         int newSliderValue = sharedPreferences.getInt("sliderValue", 0);
    }
}
```

For me the tricky part was to register the shared preferences to the change listener. Thankfully, I found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667088/onpreferencechange-method-isnt-called-when-listpreferences-changes).

I guess the code is similar for `Preference Fragment` :-)